# dereferencing typecasted void *object pointers

Tags: c++, casting, void-pointers

With regards to this piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>

class CClass1
{
public:
    void print() {
        std::cout << "This should print first" << std::endl;
    }
};

class CClass2
{
public:
    void print() {
        std::cout << "This should print second" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

So someone asked an interesting question about having a "free pointer" (so to speak) which can point to multiple instances of different objects without having to create a new type of that object. The person had the idea that this pointer can be of type `void *` and since it is void, it can be made to point to any instance of an object and access the object's public properties.

The following solution was submitted:

```
int main() {
    void *pClass(NULL);
    ((CClass1 *)(pClass))->print();
    ((CClass2 *)(pClass))->print();
    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

My question is why does the above work, but this doesn't:

```
int main() {
    (CClass1 *FG)->print();
    (CClass2 *FG)->print();
    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first one doesn't work, either. It's not pointing to a proper object.

Comment: It compiled fine for me, which is why I started experimenting

@chris that is exactly why I was amazed it worked because there is no real object to point to but it still printed the correct things

Comment: You'll come to love that compiling it is only half the battle, generally the easy half.

Comment: @chris it also executed i.e. it printed the correct output for each time the class was called. Compiler I use: gcc version 4.7.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1)

Comment: But it's still ultimately undefined behaviour, and appearing to work is just one of the ways it can screw you over (probably the worst).

Comment: Yep, it causes a seg fault when I add variables to the class then try to print the variables the same way.

Thanks for your input

Answer (score 1):

Your first example exhibits undefined behavior, by calling a non-static member function via a pointer that doesn't point to a valid object. It only appears to work by accident, because the function in question just happens not to use `this` in any way.

Your second example is, quite simply, syntactically incorrect. I'm not even sure what you are trying to do there; the code makes no sense.

Comment: I was trying to replicate what the first code was doing. It wasn't pointing to a valid object which is why I thought I should try the second code and see what happens.